# Twilio Programmable video frames per second

Tags: video, twilio, frames

Hi I am working with Twilio Programmable video chat application using nodejs. I have a requirement like I need to disable the video programatically if frames per second goes beyond 7. How to achieve this, help please.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using the `Room`'s API. A [`Room` object has a `getStats` method](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Room.html#getStats__anchor) that returns a promise that resolves to an array of [`StatsReport`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/StatsReport.html) objects. a `StatsReport` object has a `remoteVideoTrackStats` property which is an array of the remote videos' stats, each of which is a [`RemoteVideoTrackStats` object](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/RemoteVideoTrackStats.html) that has a `frameRate` property.

So, with your room you can call:

```
room.getStats().then((statsReports) => {
  statsReports.forEach((statsReport) => {
    statsReport.remoteVideoTrackStats.forEach((videoTrackStats) => {
      console.log(videoTrackStats.frameRate);
    });
  });
});
```

You can then sample these framerates at a reasonable interval and selectively turn the videos on and off as you need.

I've not worked with this myself personally, but I am pretty sure that the stats reports are what you need here. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, I was able to get the framerate as you suggested. However, I want to restrict the framerate to 10. I have used below setting to do that.

var connectOptions = {
      name: roomName,
 video: { width: 450, framerate: 10 }
    };
Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function(error) {
      log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
    });

Eventhough, framerate set to 10. While on the call, I am getting almost 15 to 20 framerate per second. 

Please help me how to restrict the framerate.

Comment: The [MDN article on constraints shows that you need to use camel case for `frameRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Frame_rate).

Comment: Thank you, your help saved me much. I need to pass date filters(StartDate & EndDate) in the below api. Please help.  client.taskrouter.v1
.workspaces(workspaceSid)
.workers
.statistics()
.fetch()
.then((responseData) => {
     console.log(responseData.cumulative.reservations_accepted);
});